# Angular 2 Accent Folding

Tags: angular, typescript, typeahead

Hello I am struggeling to solve a problem I have:

I've got an input field with autocompletion. I'd like to have accent folding for it.

E.g.

When I search with the term `mun` these two words should show up `Dortmund & München`

What I currently have is that if I search with the term `mün` that it lists `Dortmund`. But not `München`

```
accentMap = {
  'ü': 'u',
  'Ü': 'u',
  'ä': 'a',
  'Ä': 'a',
  'ö': 'o',
  'Ö': 'o'
};

let str = '';
for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  str += this.accentMap[input.charAt(i)] || input.charAt(i);
}
```

I then make a call with the `str` to an API that returns those entries like `Dortmund` or `München`.

Comment: What kind of `typeahead` are you using? Is it provided by any lib?

Comment: ng2 bootstrap typeahead

Comment: I read their docs and I found the `typeaheadLatinize` input. Doesn't It work in this case?

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not

Comment: If I am to believe the [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/typeahead#typeahead-directive), the built in `typeaheadLatinize` option solves exactly this problem, and it is supposed to be enabled by default. So you shouldn't have to write any custom code for this.

If it's not working you should probably raise an issue with the authors of the Angular 2 Bootstrap components.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your code is always converting "mün" to "mun", and thus, the string is found in "Dortmund" but never in "München".

To fix this, first wrap your code in a reusable function:

```
function removeAccents(input: string){
    let accentMap = {
      'ü': 'u',
      'Ü': 'u',
      'ä': 'a',
      'Ä': 'a',
      'ö': 'o',
      'Ö': 'o'
    };

    let str = '';

    for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      str += this.accentMap[input.charAt(i)] || input.charAt(i);
    }

    return str;
}
```

And then when you want to compare the input against the list of words, use a statement like this:

```
if(removeAccents(input) == removeAccents(word)){
   // The input matched the word
}
```